# A book that has exercises which closely resembles the content of Lorenzo's Stochastic Volatility Modeling book?

Tags: stochastic-volatility, reference-request

I'm currently going through Lorenzo Bergomi's book *Stochastic Volatility Modeling*. The one issue I have is that it does not contain exercises to test your knowledge and learn.  Is there a textbook that is very similar so I can test my knowledge?

Comment: “_Very similar_” in which sense?

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw similar topics so I can practice the content

Comment: When it came out it was considered a unique and original book so may be hard to find equivalent

Comment: @nbbo2 The book also has the feel that its sole purpose is to be a practitioner's reference, rather than for a learning textbook.

Answer (score 1):

You can check Sebastien Bossu's book "Advanced Equity Derivatives"
Not going as deeply as Lorenzo's book but it contains lot of exercises which make it richer